# What does expandablelistview error in AndrioStudio mean?

Tags: android, main-activity

This is the main-activity where the error occurs

```
public class MainActivity extends ListActivity {
     @Override
     public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
     super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    // storing string resources into Array
    String[] adobe_products = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.Events);

    // Binding resources Array to ListAdapter
    this.setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<>(this, R.layout.list_data, R.id.label, adobe_products));

    ListView lv = getListView();

    // listening to single list item on click
    lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> a, View v, int position, long id) {
            // In the following line "v" refers to the View returned by the `getView()` method; meaning the clicked View.
            TextView txtName = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.product_label);
            String name;
            name = txtName.getText().toString();
            switch (name) {
                case "Sports":
                    Intent intent;
                    intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Sports.class);
                    startActivity(intent);
                    break;

                case "Lunch":
                    Intent intent1;
                    intent1 = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Lunch.class);
                    startActivity(intent1);
                    break;

                case "contacts":
                    Intent intent2;
                    intent2 = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Contacts.class);
                    startActivity(intent2);
                    break;
            }

        }
    });

}
```

}

This is the error

java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.CharSequence android.widget.TextView.getText()' on a null object reference
            at com.example.trobinson.fblaproject.MainActivity$1.onItemClick(MainActivity.java:38)
            at android.widget.AdapterView.performItemClick(AdapterView.java:300)
            at android.widget.AbsListView.performItemClick(AbsListView.java:1143)
            at android.widget.AbsListView$PerformClick.run(AbsListView.java:3044)
            at android.widget.AbsListView$3.run(AbsListView.java:3833)
            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5221)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:899)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694)
02-06 09:52:44.609      938-962/? E/gralloc_goldfish﹕ gralloc_alloc: Mismatched usage flags: 576 x 576, usage 333
02-06 09:52:44.609      938-962/? E/﹕ GraphicBufferAlloc::createGraphicBuffer(w=576, h=576) failed (Invalid argument), handle=0x0
02-06 09:52:44.624    1249-1280/system_process E/BufferQueueProducer﹕ [ScreenshotClient] dequeueBuffer: createGraphicBuffer failed
02-06 09:52:44.629    1249-1280/system_process E/ActivityManager﹕ Invalid thumbnail dimensions: 576x576
02-06 10:12:01.500    2233-2233/? E/memtrack﹕ Couldn't load memtrack module (No such file or directory)
02-06 10:12:01.500    2233-2233/? E/android.os.Debug﹕ failed to load memtrack module: -2
02-06 10:12:01.963    2243-2243/? E/libprocessgroup﹕ failed to make and chown /acct/uid_10054: Read-only file system
02-06 10:12:08.952    2243-2243/com.example.trobinson.fblaproject E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.trobinson.fblaproject, PID: 2243

we arent sure what to do about it.

Comment: Please provide a decent code sample of where the exception occurrs and the full error description. With out that it's very hard for us to decide what wen wrong

Comment: Check you're tags, the title says Android Studio your tag says eclipse

Comment: java.lang.NullPointerException <--- Some variable or UI Element has not been initialized. Sort of like if you have a variable and forgot to initialize it.

"int p;"

Comment: ok how would we fix then @paul?

Comment: Odds on bet that whatever is at line 38 never got initialized. What line is 38?

Comment: this is line 38:name = txtName.getText().toString();

Answer (score 0):

```
ListView lv = getListView();
```

I figured it out. "getListView" actually doesnt initialize your listview.

Comment: how would we initialize it?

Comment: Show us your getListView() - But a normal intialization is to define what your variable is. In your case a listview. So the syntax would be like this0:


lv = (listview) findviewbyid(r.id.yourlistviewname);

Comment: we looked for the getListView() but we couldnt find it. so that maybe the problem now.

Comment: getListView is a method. Just right click and "Go to definition". I think f2 will do the same for you.

Comment: well we couldn't find "definition" but we found "declaration" could that be the same thing?

Comment: Theyve changed the keybinding in Android Studio apaprently. Either press Ctrl+b when you have the object targeted or right click > go to > declaration. 

Thing is that SO is a website for people who have rudimentary understanding of programming. If you dont know how to even intialize a variable I dont think youre gonna solve your issue.

Answer (score 0):

In your adapter you are mapping the array contents to `R.id.label`, but in the `onClick()` you're looking for `R.id.product_label`. If this is in the same layout, you shouldn't net null-pointered, but I'm guessing it's actually in a different layout.

If the line that's throwing is indeed `name = txtName.getText().toString();`, the only things that can throw `NullPointerException` are `txtName` and `txtName.getText()`. Set a breakpoint at line 38. It `txtName` is `null`, it means that the `id` you're looking for isn't in the view that was clicked. if `txtName` is not `null`, the text in `txtName` never got set.

Comment: that wasnt the problem though it says its the code in line 38: name = txtName.getText().toString();